# System.OverflowException: "The arithmetic operation caused an overflow." VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

When I try to perform a search on my function based on a phone number with eg. 4444444444, this exception comes to me. How can I fix it?

This is my code:

```
    If IsNumeric(Trim(tbNumSearch.Text)) Then
        SearchByNumber(Val(tbNumSearch.Text)) 'this is where I get the error
    End If


  Sub SearchByNumber(ByVal telNumber As Integer)
 End Sub
```

But when I search with eg. 4444, I don't get this error.

I suppose I'm making a mistake in the conversion. Maybe this is a 64 bit number. Anyway, I can't find a solution. Please help.

Comment: `Val` returns a `Double` which is 64 bit floating point. So it can handle `4444444444`. What type is the parameter in `SearchByNumber`? If you put this `Option Strict On` at the top of your code, it may tell you the problem.

Comment: Please also share your SearchByNumber method - specifically the bits where it falls over.

Comment: @djv and yes, from the "SearchByNumber" method, the input parameter is integer

Comment: @djv when i set this (ByVal  telNumber As Int64)  up then i no longer make a mistake, was that a problem?
instead of (ByVal telNumber As Integer)

Comment: A Telephone number is not a *number*, it's a string. You don't add, multiply or otherwise apply math functions to Phone numbers. Not a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing `SearchByNumber()` expects an `Integer`. Signed `Integer` values only go up to about 2 billion, and can't express anything higher. In other words, it's not large enough to handle US phone numbers, which could get close to 10 billion, or 20 billion with the long-distance prefix.

You could fix this by changing to a `Long`, or by using `Strings`.

Answer (score 2):

Put `Option Strict On` and it will tell you

> Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Double' to 'Integer'

[image]

which means you should pass an integer to the function instead.

Also, unfortunately, the number 4444444444 is too large for `Integer` which is a 32 bit number, and the maximum value it can hold is 2147483647

[image]

So you can either

Change the declaration of `SearchByNumber` to take a 64 bit integer

```vb
Sub SearchByNumber(ByVal telNumber As Long)
```

or not use such large numbers, but I guess this isn't an option.

I would also convert to an integral number type instead, and at the same time stop using outdated functions (like `Val`). `Long` and `Long.TryParse()` are good options.

```vb
Dim l As Long
If Long.TryParse(Trim(tbNumSearch.Text), l) Then SearchByNumber(l)
```

```vb
Sub SearchByNumber(telNumber As Long)

End Sub
```